# Multiline arguments to Python's .format

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I'd like to be able to print strings like this:

```
text1 v1 text2 v3
      v2       v4
```

where the `vi` are variables. I tried this:

```
"text1 {} text2 {}".format("v1\nv2", "v3\nv4")
```

But, predictably, this gives the output

```
text1 v1
v2 text2 v3
v4
```

because the line break in first argument to `format` applies to the whole line.

Is there any nice way to pass multiline arguments to `format` without breaking the formatted string as a whole?

Comment: There's a library [just for this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

Comment: lol nope .... thats not how the terminal works ... you might want to look into control characters, and or curses... although that said @dhke 's answer might solve your problem more or less

Comment: @HansSchwabing, check my answer I guess you ask for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install tabulate
```

Pretty-print tabular data in Python, a library and a command-line
utility.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
table =[["text1", "v1", "text2", "v3"],["", "v2", "", "v4"]]
print(tabulate(table))
```

"table" is parent list and element of it will be rows of the table to be print.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this

```
In [1]: print "text1 {} text2 {}\n      {}       {}".format("v1", "v3", "v2", "v4")
text1 v1 text2 v3
      v2       v4
```

OR

```
In [2]: print "text1\t{}\ttext2\t{}\n\t{}\t{}".format("v1", "v3", "v2", "v4")
text1   v1  text2   v3
        v2          v4
```

The `\t` means tab, and `\n` is newline.